# How to fill different ComboBoxes in a DataGridView control with C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I have a datagridview with 3 comboboxes.
When in combobox 1 (=Rownumber = 1) AA is selected then at runtime combobox2 has to be filed with some value. 
This value is comming from a DataTable.
When some value is selected in combobox2 (Also RowNumber = 1), then at runtime combobox3 (also RowNumber = 1) has to be filled with some value also comming from a DataTable.

Above means that when combobox1 where the columnindex is 0 has the value:
AA
BB
CC

When AA is selected ComboBox2 where the columnindex is 0 must have the value (ComboBox2 is must be filled at runtime and the values are comming from a DataTable):
11
22
33

When 11 is selected ComboBox3 where the columnindex is 0 must have the value (ComboBox3 is must be filled at runtime and the values are comming from a DataTable):
Name
LastName
Address
City

THEN THE NEXT ROW

At RowNumber 2 ComboBox1 has the value:
AA
BB
CC

when BB is selected, ComboBox2 also at RowNumber 2 must have the value (ComboBox2 is must be filled at runtime and the values are comming from a DataTable):
Pipo
Peppie
Clown

when Pipo is selected, ComboBox3 also at RowNumber 2 must have the value (ComboBox3 is must be filled at runtime and the values are comming from a DataTable):
Yes
No
Maybe

I have tried a lot but nothing works.
Is above possible and how in C#?

Comment: @user439997: I think your question is bit confusing. All these comboboxes are in same column in different rows or in same row different columns. can you clarify that? I can give you a solution if you clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

you can define parameter option for the Dropdowns in the Configure Datasource and you can set the parameter source to any other control.

For Ex: if u have 2 dropdown den you can bind the 2nd dropdown with the first one ven you select the items in 1st dropdown the items in the 2nd dropdown also get changes automatically.